# SQL Server: many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

So I am having a brain meltdown when trying to figure this one out. What I have is a few database's like:

**tblGenre**

```
genreID
genreName
```

**tblArtist**

```
artistID
artistName
genreID
```

**tblAlbum**

```
albumID
albumName
artistID
```

Everything is all well and good, and working fine. Ok, now with the question...

What I am trying to figure out is how to link an artist who has multiple names. I.e. the artist 'Prince'. I have albums from him, who I would catalog under 3 different bands; Prince (artistID=5), Prince and the new power generation (artistID=17, and "Symbol" (artistID=43)...

So, When I lookup the artist "Prince", who has a artistID of 5, how can I link the other 2 bands up to this one? Would I create a seperate database the has a comma-separated values of each artistID (i.e. 5,17,43) or is there an easier way to do this?

I don't want to go as far as the album level, of who played on every album in my database. I just want to create a link of artists who have been with multiple bands. Just a few more examples of how I would want "hooked together"...

- Tom Petty (Classic Rock)

  - Tom Petty & the Heartbreakers (Classic Rock)
  - Tom Petty & the Heartbreakers (Soundtrack)
- Prince (Funk)

  - Prince & the New Power Generation (Funk)
- Mark Knopfler (Classic Rock)

  - Mark Knopfler (Soundtrack)
  - Dire Straits (Classic Rock)

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Quote: "Would I create a seperate database the has a comma seperated values of each artistID (i.e. 5,17,43)" - NEVER do something like this, 1st normal form exists for a reason.

Comment: I think that more relationships (not 'relations', BTW) exist in your data model than you currently have tables for e.g. where an artist has albums in more than one genre (e.g. hasn't Mark Knopfler done country albums?), where more than one artist contributes to an album, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices:

1) ARTISTS table and ARTISTS_ALIASES table, where artistid is a foreign key  in the ARTISTS_ALIASES table, and you would have an artist_aliasid in your ALBUM table, so you'd know under what name the artist appeared on that album; or

2) a single ARTISTS using recursion (like EMPLOYEE BOSS table):

```
                artistid
                artistname
                primaryartistid  (references artistid in this table
```

When artistid and primaryartistid are the same, you treat that row as the "base" artist.

Comment: Although I offered it, I wouldn't choose option #2 here, where there are only two levels, the base artist and the alias(es). Option #2 is good for a hierarchy of arbitrary depth, e.g. the employee's supervisor's supervisor's supervisor. Option #1 meets the KISS principle here.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table like **tblRelatedArtists** which has two columns: .artistID and .relatedArtistID.

When you query the database, you could inner join the **tblArtist** 
`where .artistID is in (select relatedArtistID from tblRelatedArtists as innerArtists where innerArtists.artistID = outerArtists.artistID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Drew, it sounds like the tblArtist is more band than the main performer for an album.  I see you have vb listed in the question so I also assume you have a vb front end on this app.  With all these assumptions I suggest you add a varchar column to tblArtist called altArtistId. Add this column to your retun record set in your front end.  Parse the comma seperated list and return to tblArtist to get any related information.